# Delay Toggling For One Of Multiple Elements in On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the basic function below which toggles the same '.closed' class for two different elements at the same time. I need to find a solution to change NAV element's class with some delay. I tried to use the delay() but as far I as understand it works only with animated elements.

I was able to opdain the effect I want only by adding CSS transition to the NAV element, but would like to have JQuery solution. Could you please direct me to a right solutions. Thanks

NOTE: I use JQuery UI to add duration to toggleClass

```js
$('.menu-items').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.menu-item, nav').toggleClass("closed", 500); //this one to be changed
});
```

```css
nav{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 9999 ;
}
nav.closed{
  z-index: 0 !important;
}

nav .menu-item{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
  -moz-background-size: cover !important;
  -o-background-size: cover !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#m1.closed,
#m2.closed,
#m3.closed,
#m4.closed{
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<nav>
  <div id="m1" class="menu-item">
    <div class="inner ab-ctr">
      <h2 class="ab-ctr">menu1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="m2" class="menu-item">
    <div class="inner ab-ctr">
      <h2 class="ab-ctr">menu2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="m3" class="menu-item">
    <div class="inner ab-ctr">
      <h2 class="ab-ctr">menu3</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="m4" class="menu-item">
    <div class="inner ab-ctr">
      <h2 class="ab-ctr">menu4</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

UPDATE: Guys, thanks for answers. But I didn't take to consideration that I need different timing only for the "close" class. As an example, I need to change NAVs class in one second after I changed '.menu-item's class (I already did it with setInteval), however once I toggle back the NAV has to change its value immediately without any delay. Is it also possible with setInterval or I need to find another less complicated solution? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the function which does exactly what I want. Thanks everyone for the efforts :)

```
var menu = $('.menu-item');
var content = $('.content');
var menuItems = $('.inner');
var toToggle = $('.menu-item, nav');
var toggled = false;



menuItems.on('click', function(){
    if (!toggled){
        toToggle.addClass("closed", 1000); //adds class with same timing
        toggled = true;
    }
    else {
        $('nav').removeClass('closed', function(){ //removes class immediately
            menu.removeClass('closed', 1000); //removes class during one secend
        });
        toggled = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native JS event [`.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout):

```
$('.menu-items').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        // Delay for 1 second (1000ms)
        var timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $('.menu-item, nav').toggleClass("closed"); 
        }, 1000);
});
```

---

**Update**

Since you are looking for difference behaviour depending on the class toggled you might as well simulate the toggle with and `if...else`. This way you can add the timeout only when adding the close class. For example:

```
$('.menu-items').click(function(){
    // Delay for 1 second (1000ms)
    var toggled = $('.menu-item,nav');
    if($(toggled).hasClass("closed")) {
        toggled.removeClass("closed");
    } else {
        var timer = setTimeout(function(){
            toggled.addClass("closed");
        }, 1000); 
    }
});
```

[**Simple Fiddle Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ojfww7f/). Note that it takes 1 second to add the class `closed` but is immediate when you remove the class.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it partly solved my issue, but I need some improvement :) I updated my question. If I won't find any solution I will mark your question as a correct one as it did almost what I want :) Thanks again.

Comment: @EmilGurbanov No problem, see my updated answer for the new functionality.

Comment: I tried this way, but it does't for for me again, it animates blocks to the only on toggle, on toggle backs it crashes animation and the idea itself :)

Comment: Please see the working example http://jsfiddle.net/8a3vqy5v/4/, once you click to toggle back content layer is on the front and disappears only once animation done.

Comment: @EmilGurbanov You can add a second parameter to add a transition for your animation for `removeClass` and `addClass`, [for example](http://jsfiddle.net/8a3vqy5v/5/).

Comment: Doesn't it have the same animation crash? It worked for me the same way only if I add transition with timing to the nav. But I want it work without transition.

Comment: @EmilGurbanov For me both me newest example on your toggle works in the same way in both Firefox and Chrome, I don't anything wrong with the animation. Or anything different, other than the delay.

Comment: Odd.. In my case the elements close fine, but when I click them to toggle back, Z-Index of the content element changes after the block animate back on background.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple `setTimeout()`:

```
$('.menu-items').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
            $('.menu-item, nav').toggleClass("closed");
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is window.setTimeout().  It takes two arguments, the first is a function to run after the timeout and the second is how long to delay.  More information is available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

`toggleClass()` does support transition duration so you don't need an external implementation to handle this. Make sure you have references to `jquery ui`.

```
$('.menu-item').click(function(){  

    var $thisId = this.id;
    $('.menu-item').each(function()
    { 
        if(this.id != $thisId)
         $(this).addClass("closed",2000);

    }); 
    $(this).toggleClass("closed active",2000);

});
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/g8cL0uuc